# How do I create a new C++ project in Xcode?

Tags: c++, xcode, xcode4.6

I'm not sure how to create a *pure* C++ project with Xcode 4.6:

[image: image of trying to create a new project]

Comment: OSX->application->Command Line Tool and choose type C++

Answer (score 137, accepted):

I'll explain how to make C++ or C project in the new XCode 4 or later. (This does work in XCode 6.2)

[image: First Step]
[image: Second Step]