# How to run C++ from Xcode 5.02

Tags: xcode, xcode5

I haven't used Xcode in awhile and overall new to macs. How od I run a C++ program from Xcode V5.02. I don't see a command line function anymore?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Xcode supports c++ in `objective-c` projects through `.mm` files, but not on its own.

**UPDATE**: Guess I was wrong, see here: http://neilmonday.blogspot.com/2008/02/how-to-compile-basic-c-programs-in.html and here: [How do I create a new C++ project in XCode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14803774/how-can-i-make-a-c-project-in-xcode)

Run `xcode-select --install` to make sure you command line tools installed on the system.

Comment: On the contrary, you can create and compile C++ and a .mm means Objective-C++

Comment: My Xcode has it, I believe the difference is that you dont have command line tools installed.Starting in mavericks, they have to be installed separately from Xcode. Type the following into Terminal: xcode-select --install then you should see it.

Answer (score 4):

In Xcode, select **File>New>Project**.  Then navigate to the **Application tab** under OS X.  The last choice will be **"Command Line Tool"**.  Hit Next.  Then, **select C++** in the type pulldown menu at the bottom.  Name your project, hit next, choose a place to save, and click Create.  You will see a file called main.cpp.  Select it, and you're ready to go!

Answer (score 0):

See [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9329325/451475) for help with command line tool installation.

Basically the terminal

command is

> xcode-select --install

The other option is to create a C++ Command Line tolls project.